# Fire & smoke not showing in render, but only in viewport

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, node-editor, 3d-view, fire

I have spent some time playing with fire & blender nodes, once I render a scene nothing shows up sadly.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You turned off the domain's render visibility in the outliner.

[image]

Turn it back on.